# How to set a state Array from a global variable in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, asynchronous

I'm trying to set a state variable to the value of a global variable inside componentWillMount.

I'm making API calls based on the user's interests (using forEach function) and I`m trying to store the results in a global variable to latter store it in a state variable ( user:{articles}).

For some reason in the render the `this.state.user.articles` variable is always empty. Am I missing something ?

Here is how I set the initial value :

```
class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        user :{
            articles: [],
        }
    }
    this.componentWillMount.bind(this);
}
```

Here is where I make my API calls and try to use `this.setState` to update the varialbe

```
async componentWillMount(){
        const loggedUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
        const userEntry = await API.get(apiName,path + loggedUser.username);
        console.log(userEntry)
        currentInterests = userEntry.userInterests;
        currentInterests.forEach(async function (interest) {
          console.log(interest);
          let query = 'q='+interest+'&';
          let url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?' +
              query +
              'from=2019-02-22&' +
              'sortBy=popularity&' +
              'apiKey=hiddenforsecurity';

          let req = new Request(url);

            const response = await fetch(req);
            const json = await response.json();
            console.log(typeof json.articles);
            for(var key in json.articles){
                results.push(json.articles[key])
            }
            console.log(results[15]);


      });

     this.setState({
         user : {
             articles: results,
         }
     })
    }
```

While `console.log(results[15])` returns the expected element, in the render the `console.log(this.state.user.articles)` from

```
render() {

       console.log(this.state.user.articles)
       return (
           <ul>
               {this.state.user.articles.map((article, index) => {
                   console.log(article.author)
                   return (<li key={index}>{article.author}</li>)})}
           </ul>
       );

}
```

return an empty array, as the one set in the constructor which means that the function

```
 this.setState({
     user : {
         articles: results,
     }
 })
```

from componentWillMount has no effect. What am I missing? I've tried countless fixes online and nothings seems to work.

Comment: I can give you some suggestions
1. use API calls in componentDidMount , 2. const loggedUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser(); const userEntry = await API.get(apiName,path + loggedUser.username);
these calls you can add to componentDidMount and set as state
Q. why you need to use async await in componentWillMount ?

Comment: Beacause the API calls are asyncronous and i`lve use componentDidMount before, no effect what so ever.

Comment: Have you tried to set your array ( in the componentWillMount ) with some mockup values ? something like `[{author:'a'},{author:'b'},{author:'c'}]` and see if it renders as you wish ?  And BTW you should change to `ComponentDidMount` as WillMount one is now deprecated

Comment: lifecycle methods dont need binding

Comment: By the way, `componentWillMount` was deprecated. Use `componentDidMount` instead

Comment: It does render yes, I`ve tried that before. The values in the array that I`m trying to pass to the state variable look like this {source: {…}, author: "Jenny List", title: "Teach Computing The Old-School Way With A Digi-Comp II", description: "Ubiquitous computing has delivered a world in whic…ter they can easily do so from a multitude of de…", url: "https://hackaday.com/2019/02/25/teach-computing-the-old-school-way-with-a-digi-comp-ii/", …}

Comment: I`m using componentDidMount now, still no effect

Comment: see @Quince answer I think he's got the point ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that `forEach` will not wait for each callback to have run. In the example below, `done` will be printed before the array elements (`thing1`, `thing2`, `thing3`).

```js
const things = ["thing1", "thing2", "thing3"];

//https://gist.github.com/eteeselink/81314282c95cd692ea1d
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const exampleFunction = async() => {
  things.forEach(async(thing) => {
    await delay(500);
    console.log(thing);
  });

  console.log("done");
}


exampleFunction();
```

In your example, the state will be set before the results have actually been processed.

One way this can be avoided is by using a `for` loop so that each statement can be `await`ed upon

```js
const things = ["thing1", "thing2", "thing3"];

//https://gist.github.com/eteeselink/81314282c95cd692ea1d
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const exampleFunction = async() => {

  for (let index = 0; index < things.length; index++) {
    await delay(500);
    console.log(things[index]);
  };

  console.log("done");
}

exampleFunction();
```

Comment: Yes, this fixed it. Thanks a lot. I was not sure if you can have an asyncronous function inside the forEach function. Changing the forEach to a normal for solved it.

Comment: good to hear. If this has fully solved your issue then you can mark this answer or the other answer that makes use of a nice `Promise.forAll` approach, as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is called before the `forEach` is complete, here's a simple illustration :

```js
const arr = [ 1, 2, 3,4,5];

arr.forEach(async e => {
 const a = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    
 console.log(a)                   
})

console.log('after the loop')
```

Update your `componentWillMount` to use `Promise.all` like :

```
async componentWillMount(){
  const loggedUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
  const userEntry = await API.get(apiName,path + loggedUser.username);

  currentInterests = userEntry.userInterests;

  const promises = currentInterests.map(interest => {
    let query = 'q='+interest+'&';
    let url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?' +
        query +
        'from=2019-02-22&' +
        'sortBy=popularity&' +
        'apiKey=hiddenforsecurity';

    let req = new Request(url);

    return fetch(req);
  })

  const results = await Promise.all(promises)
                               .then(res => res.map(e => e.json()))
                               .then(res => res.map(res.articles));

  this.setState({
    user : {
        articles: results,
    }
  })
}
```